# Changing colors using buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button

Is there a way for me to write less lines of codes for this function? I want it so that when you press either one of the buttons it will alternate between the two colors. function green() is the exact opposite of red.

```html
<h1 id="header">Red Or Green</h1>
<button id="redButton" onclick="red()">Red</button>
<button id="greenButton" onclick="green()">Green</button>
```

```
function red() {
  document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "Red"
  document.getElementById('header').style.color = "red"
  document.getElementById('redButton').style.color = "white"
  document.getElementById('redButton').style.backgroundColor = "red"
  document.getElementById('greenButton').style.color = "black"
  document.getElementById('greenButton').style.backgroundColor = "grey"
}
```

Comment: Hm. Does the green button have a red background with white letters if selected like the red button?

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Cache the frequently accessed elements
const headerElement = document.getElementById("header");
const redButton = document.getElementById("redButton");
const greenButton = document.getElementById("greenButton");

// Event listener for the whole document, utilizing event delegation
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  const targetId = event.target.id;
  
  if (targetId === "redButton") {
    headerElement.innerHTML = "Red";
    headerElement.style.color = "red";
    redButton.classList.add("active-red");
    greenButton.classList.remove("active");
  } else if (targetId === "greenButton") {
    headerElement.innerHTML = "Green";
    headerElement.style.color = "green";
    greenButton.classList.add("active-green");
    redButton.classList.remove("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: white;
}

.active-red {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.active-green {
  color: black;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header">Red Or Green</h1>
<button id="redButton">Red</button>
<button id="greenButton">Green</button>
```

Comment: Green button is wrong

Answer (score 2):

You can try passing the color, based on which you can set the styles of the buttons like the following way:

```js
function toggleColor(color) {
    const header = document.getElementById('header');
    const redButton = document.getElementById('redButton');
    const greenButton = document.getElementById('greenButton');
    
    //set header text & color based on the color passed
    header.textContent = color === 'red' ? 'Red' : 'Green';
    header.style.color = color;
    
    //set red button's text & background color
    redButton.style.color = color === 'red' ? 'white' : 'black';
    redButton.style.backgroundColor = color === 'red' ? 'red' : 'grey';
    
    //set green button's text & background color
    greenButton.style.color = color === 'green' ? 'white' : 'black';
    greenButton.style.backgroundColor = color === 'green' ? 'green' : 'grey';
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header">Red Or Green</h1>
<button id="redButton" onclick="toggleColor('red')">Red</button>
<button id="greenButton" onclick="toggleColor('green')">Green</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create CSS classes instead and you can add and remove them based on your requirement.

The following can be created:

```js
function red() {
  document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "Red"
  document.getElementById('header').style.color = "red"
  document.getElementById('redButton').classList.add("active-red");
  document.getElementById('greenButton').classList.add("inactive");
}

function green() {
  document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "Green"
  document.getElementById('header').style.color = "green"
  document.getElementById('redButton').classList.add("inactive");
  document.getElementById('greenButton').classList.add("active-green");
}
```

```css
.inactive{
  color: black;
  background-color: grey;     
}

.active-red{
  color: white;
  background-color: red;   
}

.active-green{
  color: white;
  background-color: green;   
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header">Red Or Green</h1>
<button id="redButton" onclick="red()">Red</button>
<button id="greenButton" onclick="green()">Green</button>
```

Comment: some errors : `TypeError: document.getElementById(...).add is not a function"`

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:
with a `<div id="buttons-group">`

```js
const
  e_header  = document.querySelector('#header')
  e_buttons = document.querySelector('#buttons-group')
  ;
e_buttons.onclick = e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('button')) return;
  
  e_buttons.className = e_header.className = e.target.id; 
   
  e_header.textContent = e.target.textContent;
  }
```

```css
#buttons-group>button {
  color            : black;
  background-color : grey;
  width            : 5em;
  }
#header.redButton   { color: red;   }
#header.greenButton { color: green; }

#buttons-group.redButton>#redButton {
  color            : white;
  background-color : red;
  }
#buttons-group.greenButton>#greenButton {
  color            : white;
  background-color : green;
  }
```

```html
<h1 id="header">Red Or Green</h1>
<div id="buttons-group">
  <button id="redButton"> Red   </button>
  <button id="greenButton"> Green </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a DRY solution have one event handler that covers both button click events.

1. You should remove your inline JS from the markup and use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
2. Use CSS classes, and add/remove/toggle them with [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
3. Add data attributes to your buttons to identify the colours. Use this value to swap between red and green.

```js
// Grab the elements, and add listeners to the buttons
const header = document.querySelector('.header');
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
btns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick));

// When a button is clicked...
function handleClick(e) {
  
  // Grab the colour from its dataset
  const { color } = this.dataset;
  
  // Get its opposite colour
  const oppColor = color === 'red' ? 'green' : 'red';
  
  // Remove the header opposite colour
  header.classList.remove(oppColor);
  
  // Add the header clicked colour
  header.classList.add(color);

  // Set the text content of the header to the colour
  header.textContent = color;

  // Iterate over the buttons adding the selected
  // class if the current button is the button that
  // was clicked
  btns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.classList.toggle('selected', btn === e.target);
  });
  
}
```

```css
.header { text-transform: capitalize; }
.green { color: green; }
.red { color: red; }
button { color: black; background-color: gray; }
[data-color="red"].selected { color: white; background-color: red; }
[data-color="green"].selected { color: white; background-color: green; }
```

```html
<h1 class="header">Red Or Green</h1>
<button type="button" data-color="red">Red</button>
<button type="button" data-color="green">Green</button>
```